# MongoDB query for selecting values from nested array collection

Tags: json, mongodb, nested

I am newbie to Mongo and trying to figure out how to parse through a complex nested collection.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("idVal"),
    "Ids": [{
    "mar": [{
        "se": [{
            "gootics": "UA-3-1"
        }],
        "usery": [{
            "fc0633ac-81": [{
                "sep": [{
                    "custS": "",
                    "promer": "0",
                    "reaivity": "20",
                    "stus": "active",
                    "urlist": "",
                    "upe": [
                        "mat "
                    ],
                    "whlete": ""
                }],
                "uspt": [{
                    "cor": "000000",
                    "foron": "hthp",
                    "sla": "Join!",
                    "slie": "httpsg",
                    "slile": "Jost:",
                    "suody": "We'll be in touch.",
                    "sumer": "Awesome!",
                    "tte": "qumail"
                }, {
                    "cr": "000000",
                    "refeion": "htve",
                    "sla": "Go!",
                    "slige": "httg",
                    "slle": "Hes",
                    "slle": "Mm:",
                    "tte": "rk"
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }],
    And many more such inner array’ s,
    comma separated
    }]
}
```

I need  to select the whole part of `mar` with a `mongo` query or `php`.
`db.collectionname.find({"Ids" : "mar"}).pretty()`.

This isn’t resulting anything, just being blank and tried doing `db.collectionname.find({}).pretty()`, it worked well, got all the results.

I did tried with `$elemMatch` , `$pop` etc.

Many solutions are taking very small and easy json files, no one have traversed or parsed through such complex json string. Refer some other standard process or provide your answer.

My need in zist: I will just have one of the Id's value, need to query on the basis of Id. like,
`select * from db where Id's == Id I have`; in this case it can be `mar`

Can anyone help me with writing the same query in php?? and printing the output? I am not able to do that. `"$ActualData = $collection->find(array("Ids.mar : 1"));"` but this isn't printing any value.

```
var_dump($array);
// Above line is printing this:
array (size=0)
  empty

var_dump($ActualData);
//Above line is printing this:
object(MongoCursor)[4]

//not being executed at all:
foreach($ActualData as $doc)
{
    echo "Inside it is";
    var_dump($doc);

} 
echo "Count:".count($ActualData)."\n";
//It does have 1 document
Count:1
```

Comment: Yeah! even I was thinking the same, what could be the best practice is to store Id's inside with a "id" column for every group, isn't it??

Comment: You can get output using `db.collection.find({},{"Ids.mar":1})` only if you know the key `mar`. It is strongly recommended not to use dynamic values as keys in your schema.

Comment: It is working very well, Thanks for your comments :)

Comment: Can anyone help me with writing the same query in php?? and printing the output? I am not able to do that. "$ActualData = $collection->find(array("Ids.mar : 1"));" but this isn't printing any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is strongly recommended that you should not use dynamic values as keys.**

You should use projection in query, if you want to get `mar`.

```
db.collection.find({},{"Ids.mar":1})
```

**In this case, You must know key `mar`.**

In PHP, you can convert above query as following:

```
$data = $collection->find(array(),array("Ids.mar" => 1));
```

OR

```
// Search criteria
$query = array();
// Projection (fields to include)
$projection =  array("Ids.mar" => 1);
$cursor = $collection->find($query, $projection);
foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
    //print or process here
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late response, Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Can anyone tell me drawback of using dynamic values as keys?

"Data" : {
        "Campaign Name" : "Campaign 1",
        "Ad Set Name" : "Adset 1",
        "Ad Name" : "Ad 1",
        "URL Tags" : }

I have dynamic key too in my scenario, is there anything i need to do about it??

Comment: @AbdulMoiz Dynamic keys are difficult to query. If keys are fix, it will be much easier to query on these fields.

Comment: @Vishwas: What if we are getting them from an external source, and have no control over it? What would be the best practice in this scenario?